# Four color theorem, What did I miss?

Tags: graph-theory

I am not saying that I have proven Four color theorem to be wrong, either I am saying that four-color theorem is wrong but I got one idea so I want to know what I am missing ( This is not proffesional post, probably I am not even close to "proving anything".. I just want to see solution of my map :) )

First of all, I want to mention that I am not a mathematician, and english is not my native language, so If grammar mistakes happens, I am sorry :)

According to wikipedia: "In mathematics, the four-color theorem, or the four-color map theorem, states that, given any separation of a plane into contiguous regions, producing a figure called a map, no more than four colors are required to color the regions of the map so that no two adjacent regions have the same color." ... From time to time, I take some equation or some problem in math and try to solve it (I am doing it for fun, because I like math) Today, few hours ago, I taken four-color theorem because it looked interesting ( yes, I know it is proven, "but" by computer, because of that I taken it ).. I developed dozens of "maps" and put "theorem to test" and all turned out to be false, Theorem passed all the tests... But then I developed another map, for which I could not find solution with 4 colors...To make long story short, this is the map I developed : 
http://prntscr.com/848uzb (colorfully)
http://prntscr.com/848v52 (black/white)

Apparently, I don't have enough reputation to post pictures here so I gave a links of screenshoot, and I have reputation for only 2 screenshots so I cannot post my attempts in solving this map... Anyway, I would love to see solution of "my map", So everyone who is interested to try solve is invited to try..

Comment: You must check all possible color combinations, not just one (or a few).

Comment: If you want a theorem to try and prove/disprove for yourself, you've picked a pretty nasty one.

Comment: http://grabilla.com/0580d-a0707db1-8bb5-46eb-bda9-b504a39129d3.png unless I messed up and I can't notice it that should be a valid 4-colouring

Comment: I checked (on scrap paper) and the greedy algorithm worked for me for coloring with four colors.

Comment: @Alessandro that picture would make a good answer IMHO

Comment: I'm pretty sure proving the four color theorem for graphs of that form (all edges horizontal or vertical)must be a lot easier than the full four color theorem.

Comment: @jameselmore... I am doing it for fun, it is not a serious attempt to disprove theorem.. Because I can't do it (Unless I have huge luck) I am not a mathematician :)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Here is a valid 4-colouring of your map, I found it via trial and error by hand.

Comment: Is this the only one ? Do we know how many colorations we can do just with four colors for a given map ?

Comment: this looks good, http://www.ams.org/notices/199807/thomas.pdf   after Birkhoff in 1913 and Franklin in 1922 the four-color property was proved for up to 25 regions.

Comment: Yes... I made another one hastily (this one http://prntscr.com/849ggh) but I solved it in mean time, but later I saw Alessandro also solved it, before me... I don’t have anymore any idea for map :P ... Anyway, thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 6):

Allesandro beat me to it, but here it is anyway :-)

[image: 4-colouring]

Comment: They are non-isomorphic colorings.

Comment: @dREaM: Yes, I was about to note the same :-)

Comment: I would guess that there are a lot of possible colourings, but I see no simple way to count them apart from bruteforcing all the possibilities with a computer program

Comment: @Alessandro: My sense while doing this by hand was that most of the choices were determined (up to permutations of the colours). I started at the right, nothing that the three right-most patches must have the three colours different from the outer patch, and then the two small patches in the lower centre bordering them are also determined. That left only blue or red for the central rectangle, and when I'd chosen blue there didn't seem to be many choices left. So I think it wouldn't be too much effort to count the possibilities by hand.

Comment: maybe you know, my impression was that, prior to 1976, there was a proof of the four color property for graphs with a number of regions up to some pretty impressive bound. That is, four colors was a theorem as long as the number of regions stayed below a certain bound. I have Graph Theory 1736-1936, by Biggs, Lloyd, Wilson, it does give the Heawood five color theorem, but nothing that reminds me of bounded-region-count four color.

Comment: this looks good, http://www.ams.org/notices/199807/thomas.pdf   after Birkhoff in 1913 and Franklin in 1922 the four-color property was proved for up to 25 regions.

Comment: @WillJagy: I just found [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=me3jBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA184&ots=mF1VJPWzqO&dq=birkhoff%20number%20four-color&pg=PA185#v=onepage&q&f=false). Mayer improved the bound to $96$ shortly before the theorem was proven.

Comment: thanks, that is very nice. I found some of that in an MAA article from about 1978, I think I will post two pages because it took a long time to download.

Comment: I included your book page, jpeg, with two article pages in an answer. Not sure it matters to the OP, but I like to know these things.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two pages from a summary article by John Mitchem, written shortly after the 1976 computer-aided proof; also, one page from a more recent book by Fritsch and Fritsch, reference found by joriki.  By 1975, the four color conjecture was proved for maps with up to 96 regions. Joriki also found a very nice book on the history, it puts the chronology in one neat table, and has more intermediate results than this

[image]

[image]

[image]